# Is there a way to identified the image loaded with a particular SoftLayer VM?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to find out the image name used for a particular SoftLayer VM.

I've looked around on the Soflayer UI but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to retrieve the [image template](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/) that was used to provision or reload a guest. You can use a rest API call to the [getObject](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject/) method of virtual guest service, as below:

Method: GET

```
https://username:apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/123456/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,blockDeviceTemplateGroup[name]]
```

You will get a response like below example:

```
{
    "id": 123456,
    "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
        "name": "image-template-name"
    }
}
```